# Bash script - syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: bash, shell

I have this simple bash script that keeps failing with the following messages:

`./servo.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token then'`

`./servo.sh: line 7:    if[ "$level" -eq 1 ]; then'`

And my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
level=1

while :
do
    if[ $level -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "hello"
    else
            echo "else"
    fi
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @WesCumberland's answer is correct; a tip for the future:  use http://www.shellcheck.net/ in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a space between the `if` and the `[`